Conda activate and deactivate in zsh Script
I can't seem to activate a Conda environment.  Nor deactivate it, for that matter, when turned on manually.
source /Users/rich/Applications/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
source /Users/rich/.zprofile

echo "Activating Conda environment myenv"
conda activate myenv


I just want an aliased shortcut to get this done.  My larger script has a conditional to turn it on and off, but I've put that away until I can solve this issue.
How can I use a zsh script to turn this environment on?

My alias py='zsh path/to/python_toggle.sh' should be py='source path/to/python_toggle.sh' because that initiation of a new shell is where the activation/deactivation would happen, and not in my current interactive shell.  So it was indeed happening, then that shell was terminated, not affecting my experience.
